# How to transfer OS.FILE object to the worker thread in javascript

Tags: multithreading, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Hi i am building a firefox addon . In that i am using ChromeWorer. I need to pass OS.FILE object to my worker thread .

```
var namedPipe = OS.File.open("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe",{write:true , read: true});

    namedPipe.then(
            function onSuccess(fileD) {

                npipe = fileD;
                console.log("Pipe object is " + typeof(fileD));
                twrite.postMessage({type:"init","file":fileD});
                tread.postMessage({"type":"init","file":fileD});
                console.log("Pipe Open succseded");

            },
            function onReject(reason){
                tread.terminate();
                twrite.terminate();
                console.log("Pipe Open Failed with reason " +reason);
            });
    }
```

My question is can we transfer that OS.FIlE object to my worker threads ( twrite and tread ) . If we can please tell me how to do that .

Answer (score 0):

Yes just like you did there. `ArrayBuffer` objects can be transferred. Just use the regular `postMessage` function:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker.postMessage#Parameters

Comment: I tried the same but while doing that the code stuck up there .. What i done is 

  namedPipe.then(
             function onSuccess(fileD) {
                npipe = fileD;
  var objData = {
   type : "init" , 
   file : fileD
  };
               twrite.postMessage(objData,[obj.file]);
              },

Comment: thats odd. but you know what i would recommend, i would say just do the open within the chromewoker and keep it open, no need to terminate the chromewoker, on shutdown of addon/browser/etc it automatically terminates. this way you don't have to keep sending data back and forth. just send a message to chrome worker to open file at path X and then in chromewoker store it in a global object over there until you close it.

Comment: Actually what i am doing i am creating two workers for reading and writing data on same pipe so can't open the open twice in two workers . What i am looking to open the pipe from main file and pass the file handler to both worker threads so that they can use to access the pipe synchronously.

Comment: Oh I see for multithreading, this is a good question. My solution here doesnt help at all as what is opened is not an `ArrayBuffer`